# How to downgrade or uninstall Openshift Client

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, okd

So currently I have version 3.9.14 of Openshift Client installed, I need to downgrade to version 3.9.0, but I don't know how to get 3.9.14 out of my system.

Comment: Why would you need to downgrade? It is usually better that you have the highest patch level of the X.Y version.

Comment: I joined a new team and they want us all using the same versions

Answer (score 1):

Here the client tool download links, [v3.9.0](https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/tag/v3.9.0)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Had to delete the oc executable from /usr/bin to get rid of my current version of OpenShift client, and then I downloaded version 3.9.0 and moved the executable to /usr/bin

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to remove the old version of OC. I had to go into /usr/local/Cellar and delete oc before downloading the new version.